# Why Do the Midichlorians Work with the Sith?

Tags: star-wars

After reading comments about the new book about Darth Plagueis, as usual, after reading up on anything in the Star Wars Universe, I'm left with questions.

It's stated that when Plagueis attempted to use the Force to create life, the midichlorians rebelled and blocked his attempt - and that, in response, the midichlorians created Shmi Skywalker's pregnancy in an effort to create someone who would destroy the Sith.

If the midichlorians viewed the Sith as needing destruction, then why did the midichlorians still help the Sith manipulate the Force at all?  Why not just ignore their commands and not let them interact with the Force?  Or, instead, why not just "reflect" the Sith commands back on them to destroy the Sith on their own?

Comment: Something tells me that the answer to this question is closely related to the question "Why does God allow evil to exist?"

Comment: @HNL: Okay, shall I edit it to say, "Why do midichlorians allow Sith to exist?" ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Midichlorians are an intelligent lifeforms, but only globally. Locally, they act basically as ants.

While they globally understand the threat the Sith are, they cannot do anything else than obeying theirs commands when they cast it. They just don't have the backward step to see the big picture and to discern the intentions of a force user, or event assign a command to a specific being. They also probably think on an other layer of consciousness than we are used to deals with, so thing we deem obvious is not necessarily as clear for them.

If you burn the left hand, it will probably respond as expected, but the real aftershock will come from the right hand.

Comment: But if they can't react locally, how did they prevent Plageuis from creating life on his own, then?

Comment: So, they're cellular automata with emergent intelligence? Makes sense. But if they have limited local influence, how do they assert the "Will of the Force"?

Comment: @TangoOversway Creating life is not a simple, single step task like casting lighting. Also, they not only tried to create life, but tried to create a weapon. In this case Midichlorians did had time to notify what was going on there, time to feels the threats. That's why they block this attempt took a corrective action as a whole organism.

Comment: @HNL "Will of the Force" is like a background noise, you must concentrate to listen to it, being receptive to theirs voice as a whole.